# Render multiple versions of the same Symfony form within a modal with unique ID

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a Twitter Bootstrap table where each row is an individual announcement. Each row has a button which opens up a Bootstrap dropdown with two buttons, "Edit Announcement" and "Delete Announcement". Clicking the edit button opens up a modal where the user can edit the announcement text, submitted by Symfony forms. My current implementation sends the Id of the announcement via jQuery so the Smyfony controller knows which one to edit in the database.

But now I am trying to assign a unique id to the modals, by passing in the Announcement id. However, the modal is in its own Twig template so only has access to the array of all the Announcements.

I currently moved the modal to the main template, but the symfony form buttons only show up on the first one.

The code for the modal (within the main Template that displays the table)

```
{# Delete Modal #}
                <div class="modal fade" id="delete-announcement-modal-{{ announcement.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                {{ form_start(deleteForm) }}
                                <h1 class="modal-title">
                                    <span class="fas fa-cat"></span> Srsly delete that?
                                </h1>
                                {{ form_widget(deleteForm.id) }}
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    Fine. keep it.
                                </button>
                                {{ form_widget(deleteForm.delete) }}
                                {{ form_end(deleteForm) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The controller code.

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(FormType::class)
        ->add('edit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => ' Save changes', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']))
        ->add('idd', HiddenType::class, [])

$editForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($editForm->get('edit')->isClicked() and $editForm->isValid()){
        $announcementToEdit = $em->getRepository(Announcement::class)->find($editForm->getData()['idd']);
        $announcementToEdit->setContent($request->get('content'));
        $em->flush();

        $this->logger->info(
            'Announcement edited',
            [
                'user id' => $currentUser->getId(),
                'date created' => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
                'announcement id' => $announcementToEdit->getId(),
            ]
        );
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_announcements');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest, you should update the modal instead of repeating the form.

Like this way

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('your_controller_route') }}",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#delete-announcement-modal').replaceWith($(data).find('#delete-announcement-modal'));
            $('#delete-announcement-modal').modal('show');
        }
});
```

Maybe some tweaking is necessary

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. is there no built-in way to handle this in Symfony?

Comment: I think you didnt get it right - CRUD applications never would repeat forms, because you want only edit once and so on, you have not to repeat that form. Symfony cant help, because thats basic design problem. My approach is in the middle of a full site (pure crud like examples from symfony itself) and a API based one.